# Multithreading performance overhead

Tags: python, multithreading

So basically I created this program that adds values to redis. So far I get this timing:

```
real 0m27.759s
user 0m18.129s
sys  0m5.580s
```

However when I tried to run multiple threads:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        for x in range(0, NUM_THREADS):
            Thread(None, startProgram, None,
                   (NUM_HOSTS/NUM_THREADS*x+1,
                    NUM_HOSTS/NUM_THREADS*(x+1))).start()
    except Exception as errtxt:
        print errtxt
```

I get this with `NUM_THREADS` set ot `10`:

```
real 0m32.642s
user 0m22.953s
sys  0m11.473s
```

Why is my program running *slower* with *more* threads?

I'm running Linux Ubuntu 11.04 and Python 2.7.1.

Comment: Eric, you may receive better responses if you clearly state what output you expect to receive.

Comment: I don't receive any input, my only issue was the Threading. I'm sorry for not putting enough info. It always seems like its enough to me.

Comment: The version of Python and operating system will also help in determining how threading behaves in this specific case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result depends on the Python implementation, cpython's [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) prevents parallel computations from being faster than sequential ones.

Consider using the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module, which executes each thread in its own Python process, or alternative GIL-free Python implementations like [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) and [Jython](http://www.jython.org/).

Comment: hey thanks, got it down to real 0m13.669s
user 0m13.793s
sys 0m3.968s

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com) for this.

Here is an example of parallel sum:

http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/17/31/#SUM_PRIMES

Comment: You may want to describe in more detail how Parallel Python avoids the GIL issue. As it is, it's not obvious without clicking the links that your answer really answers the question at all.