# Threading in python doesn't happen parallel

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm doing data scraping calls with an urllib2, yet they each take around 1 seconds to complete. I was trying to test if I could multi-thread the URL-call loop into threading with different offsets.

I'm doing this now with my update_items() method, where first and second parameter are the offset and limit to do loops:

```
import threading
t1 = threading.Thread(target=trade.update_items(1, 100))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=trade.update_items(101, 200))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=trade.update_items(201, 300))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

#t1.join()
#t2.join()
#t3.join()
```

Like the code, I tried to commment out the join() to prevent waiting of the threads, but it seems I get the idea of this library wrong. I inserted print() functions into the update_items() method, funny tho it shows that it's still looping just in serial routine and not all 3 threads in parallel, like I wanted to achieve.

My normal scraping protocol takes about 5 hours to complete and it's only very small pieces of data, but the HTTP call always takes some time. I want to multi-thread this task at least a few times to shorten the fetching at least to around 30-45minutes.

Comment: Bit by the [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)?

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/) seems to cover almost exactly your use-case.

Comment: It was a lot on that topic for instance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537448/python-parallel-threading)

Comment: Is the multiprocessing library reliable? It seems to be picky per OS. I'm currently running OSX Mountain Lion (latest build)

Comment: Also worth noting, unless trade.update_items(1, 100) returns a function you will want to pass the arguments using this form instead: threading.Thread(target=trade.update_items, args = (1, 100))

Comment: Thanks Paul, that seemed to work for some magical reason :). Funny tho, there seems to be a pattern where the 1st thread seems to get most priority. At the end of the 300 cycles the last 30 were all from Thread 3. But it doens't matter much. It doesn't really come to precision. As long as I can gain some speed compared to the serial looping. One more question; the loop cycles are totally light on the CPU and the HTTP data is super small. How many threads would be safe to use in this situation?

Comment: @Allendar: it is not some magical reason. In Python `f()` calls the function `f`. `f` along is the function object itself.

Comment: @FredLarson: Python releases GIL on I/O. Retrieving multiple urls in parallel is an appropriate use of threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get multiple urls in parallel limiting to 20 connections at a time:

```
import urllib2
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def generate_urls(): # generate some dummy urls
    for i in range(100):
        yield 'http://example.com?param=%d' % i

def get_url(url):
    try: return url, urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), None
    except EnvironmentError as e:
         return url, None, e

pool = Pool(20) # limit number of concurrent connections
for url, result, error in pool.imap_unordered(get_url, generate_urls()):
    if error is None:
       print result,
```

Comment: If the process is cpu+io bound, would it be fair to write
`pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())`

Comment: no. there is not enough information to make the call.

Answer (score 2):

Paul Seeb has correctly diagnosed your issue.

You are calling `trade.update_items`, and then passing **the result** to the `threading.Thread` constructor. Thus, you get serial behavior: your threads don't do any work, and the creation of each one is delayed until the `update_items` call returns.

The correct form is `threading.Thread(target=trade.update_items, args=(1, 100)` for the first line, and similarly for the later ones. This will pass the `update_items` function as the thread entry point, and the `*[1, 100]` as its positional arguments.