# How to establish 20 connections for concurrent connection tests in psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to do some concurrent connection tests and hope to establish 50 concurrent connections to the database by psycopg2 adaptor. What should I do?

Should I use the psycopg2.pool to establish concurrent connections or use Threading?

```
a = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1,50,database='test')

@contextmanager
def getcursor():
    con = a.getconn()
    con.autocommit = True
    try:
        yield con.cursor()
    finally:
        a.putconn(con)


for i in xrange(50):
    with getcursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("select * from test")
```

or should I directly create connection every time such as:

```
for i in xrange(50):
    con = psycopg2.connect(database='test',user='test', host='localhost', password='test')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from test")
    con.close()
```

Or should I create new threading every time? Thanks in advance

Comment: I used an array to store the connections and made asynchronous queries

Comment: Thanks, Jasen, I am still a little confused. could you please give me more details, if possible, a little example codes? thanks in advance

Comment: It is very simple to [parallelize this code using a thread pool](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14594205/4279) (assuming `psycopg2` releases GIL during blocking calls).

Comment: neither of those looks concurrent to me.  Aren't they just using the connections serially?  I think the test should be as close as possible to how you anticipate using it for real.